# ASP Net Identity Logout Authentication Properties Not Being Set From Identity Server Instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

For some reason parameters that are supposed to be set automatically for sign out are not being set and I can't figure out why.

I have created a new OIDC external provider. With the following settings.

```
        .AddOpenIdConnect(ExternalAuthSchemes.SkyUber, "My IDP", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

            options.Authority = "https://localhost:4000;
            options.ClientId = "MyClient";

            options.ResponseType = "id_token";

            options.SaveTokens = true;
        })
```

Using the above I can successfully authenticate and the id token is saved.

Later I want to 'sign-out'. I'm using the template for Identity server 4 and it correctly drops into its Account/logout method and knows that it has a third party provider.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout(LogoutInputModel model)
    {
        //...
        if (vm.TriggerExternalSignout)
        {
            // build a return URL so the upstream provider will redirect back
            // to us after the user has logged out. this allows us to then
            // complete our single sign-out processing.
            string url = Url.Action("Logout", new { logoutId = vm.LogoutId });

            // this triggers a redirect to the external provider for sign-out
            return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = url }, vm.ExternalAuthenticationScheme);
        }

        return View("LoggedOut", vm);
    }
```

I am able to debug the method and see that the `RedirectUri` is being set to the Account/Logout uri correctly. However when redirecting to my OP for signout neither the RedirectUri from the authentication properties **nor** the `id_token_hint`, which should be generated automatically from the saving of the Id token (options.SaveTokens = true;) are being sent. The request actually being sent is as follows.

> `https://localhost:4000/v1/account/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A53142%2Fsignout-callback-oidc&state=<STATE-STRING>-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD1_4&x-client-ver=5.2.0.0`

As you can see there is no `id_token_hint`query parameter being sent and the `post_logout_redirect_uri` is the default `https://localhost:53142/signout-callback-oidc`rather than the overridden value which should be `https://localhost:53142/account/logout?logoutId=<id>`

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why its not handling this correctly.

Many Thanks for your help.

Comment: From my experience, identity server 4 doesn't care about the uri sent in the sign out but relies on the logout uri stored on identity server.  If you have mulitple logout uris specified it will not redirect anywhere. How many post logout redirect uri's are stored in your client data?

Comment: Also, your logic seems flawed.  If vm.TriggerExternalSignout is false, the user never gets logged out you will just return to a logged out screen while the user is still logged in

Comment: This is all I do to log out and it redirects just fine   

public IActionResult LogOut()
        {
            return SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);          
        }